# How to create a custom role in Airflow helm chart

Tags: airflow, rbac

I have an Airflow instance that is about to be used by multiple teams. I need to create a segregation so that "team-1" only has access to dags with prefix "team1prefix" and so on. I was able to test it in the interface by creating a custom role with read, edit, delete permissions only to dags that they are allowed to see (using the full name of the DAG as wildcard is not allowed in UI). I want to create this custom role in helm and assign it to users based on their LDAP group, but I couldn't find a way to do it. Any ideas or experience with this kind of use case?
We use KEYCLOAK for registration.
[webserver config - LDAP current mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4cNp.png)

I created a custom role in Airflow UI - Security - List Roles - Add New Record.
After creating the role, I assigned to a user manually from the UI.

I want to do the same, but as a code in the helm chart